# Armstrong Number logic

Tags: algorithm, math, decimal

I am weak in math's hence the question I ask might be irrelevant to most here but the question is why are we dividing the Armstrong number by 10? I mean we can divide the number with any other number apart from 10.

Comment: Because you're trying to calculate digit sums in the **decimal** system.

Comment: More than likely what you are seeing is how to get a single digit from a number.  Without seeing your code though, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you don't understand what an Armstrong number is. From one web search:

An Armstrong number of three digits is an integer such that the sum of the cubes of its digits is equal to the number itself. For example, 371 is an Armstrong number since 3<sup>3</sup> + 7<sup>3</sup> + 1<sup>3</sup> = 371.

So, to check whether any random number is an Armstrong number: 243, say. Take the number as written and do 2×2×2 + 4×4×4 + 3×3×3 = 8 + 16 + 27, which is only 99, so 243 isn't an Armstrong number.

Now, there are two straightforward ways to get the individual digits of a number in a computer program. First, you can convert to a string.

```cpp
std::string theString = to_string(243);
```

And then for each digit, convert back to a number. This is kind of gross.

Or you can do this:

```cpp
int sumOfCubes = 0;
for (int newNumber = myNumber; newNumber > 0; newNumber = newNumber / 10) {
    // This is the modulus operator, or the remainder. 243 % 10 = 3.
    // 24 % 10 = 4. and 2 % 10 = 2.
    int digit = newNumber % 10;
    sumOfCubes += digit*digit*digit;
}

if (sumOfCubes == myNumber) {
    cout << myNumber << " is an Armstrong number." << endl;
}
```

What happens in the loop:

1. newNumber is initialized to myNumber (243 in my example). digit
   becomes 3 (243 divided by 10 has a remainder of 3). sumOfCubes +=
   27;
2. Then it loops. newNumber becomes newNumber / 10 as an integer, which
   is now 24. digit is 4. We add 64 to sumOfCubes.
3. Loops again. newNumber becomes 24 / 10 = 2. So we add 8.
4. Tries to loop. NewNumber becomes zero, which fails the condition, so
   the loop ends.

Done.